# Winrt Testproject using FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, mstest, fakeiteasy

I've created a Testproject for my Windows 8.1 Class Library.
In the TestInitialize function a like to fake a Service.

```
A.Fake<IService>();
```

But I get this exception:

```
The type initializer for 'FakeItEasy.Core.FakeScope' threw an exception.
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":
"System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
       at FakeItEasy.Core.FakeScope.get_Current()
       at FakeItEasy.RootModule.<RegisterDependencies>b__2(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<Register>b__0(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.Resolve(Type componentType)
       at FakeItEasy.ServiceLocator.Resolve[T]()
       at FakeItEasy.RootModule.<RegisterDependencies>b__3(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<Register>b__0(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.Resolve(Type componentType)
       at FakeItEasy.ServiceLocator.Resolve[T]()
       at FakeItEasy.RootModule.<RegisterDependencies>b__18(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<Register>b__0(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.Resolve(Type componentType)
       at FakeItEasy.ServiceLocator.Resolve[T]()
       at FakeItEasy.RootModule.<RegisterDependencies>b__17(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<Register>b__0(DictionaryContainer c)
       at FakeItEasy.IoC.DictionaryContainer.Resolve(Type componentType)
       at FakeItEasy.ServiceLocator.Resolve[T]()
       at FakeItEasy.A.get_FakeCreator()
       at FakeItEasy.A.Fake[T]()
```

When I try the same but using NUnit instead of MS-Test everthing work fine.

What do I need to change that FakeItEasy is working with MS-Test?

I'm using FakeItEasy 1.23.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Win8 or use Silverlight, so this is going to be a bit of a shot in the dark, but it may point you in the right direction.

The FakeItEasy win8 support is delivered using the same DLL we build for Silverlight.

I see that some people have had problems with Silverlight-using tests and MSTest and System.Core 5.0.5.0. To that end, perhaps looking at [Why System.Core fails to load when adding Coded UI support for Silverlight 5 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201164/adding-coded-ui-support-for-silverlight-5-application-system-core-fails-to-loa), specifically the comment by @Hans Passant that points at the [Coded UI testing support for Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/07/09/coded-ui-testing-support-for-silverlight.aspx) blog post, may help.

Or it may not. Of course, [Windows 8 Store support is experimental](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Platform-support), and there have been reports of problems with 8.1 projects. So you may still be left high and dry.